# reading results in empty config.txt file in python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, file

```
# read no. of requests
if(os.path.isfile("config.txt")):
        with open("config.txt", "r") as json_file:# Open the file for reading   
            configurations = json.load(json_file) # Read the into the buffer
            # info = json.loads(js.decode("utf-8"))
            print("read config file")
            if("http_requests_count" in configurations.keys()):
                print("present")
                print(configurations["http_requests_count"])
                number_of_requests = int(configurations["http_requests_count"])
                print(number_of_requests)
```

config.txt file from which i am reading

```
{
    "first_container_ip": "8100",
    "master_db" : "abc",
    "http_requests_count" : "8",
    "master_name" : "master",
    "slave_names" : ["slave1", "slave2", "slave3"]
}
```

later in the code, when i am opening the config file to write its giving me error like

```
io.UnsupportedOperation: not readable
```

and when i open the config file manually i find it to be empty...

Comment: Then probably *later in the code* you destroy your config file; nothing in the part you included here could be responsible for that.

Comment: `io.UnsupportedOperation: not readable` does not indicate that the file is empty, it indicates a problem with _reading_ the file. If you're opening the file to write to it, you cannot also use the same object to read it as well.

Comment: At least there's a bug that you are closing json_file twice ..  Once explicitly with `json_file.close()` and context manager (with-syntax) closes the file again.

Comment: @rasjani thats not causing the error

Comment: @Błotosmętek destroy? no, i have not. i have inserted the link to my code. have a look ?

Comment: @HampusLarsson "..cannot also use the same object ..." i have read the file using with so it closes automatically..then i open the file to write to it after making some changes to the read data ...i have inserted the link to the entire code. have a look yeah?

Answer (score 1):

In your full code example, you do

```
with open("config.txt", "w") as json_file:# Open the file for writing
    configurations = json.load(json_file) # Read the into the buffer
```

which *will* fail (can't read from a file opened for writing) *and* truncate the file (as opening with `w` does).

This is why you get the UnsupportedOperation error, and why the file ends up being empty.

I suggest refactoring things so you have two simple functions for reading and writing the configuration file:

```
def read_config():
    if os.path.isfile("config.txt"):
        with open("config.txt", "r") as json_file:
            return json.load(json_file)
    return {}


def save_config(config):
    with open("config.txt", "w") as json_file:
        json.dump(config, json_file)


def scaleup(diff):
    config = read_config()
    slave_name_list = config.get("slave_names", [])
    # ... modify things ...
    config["slave_names"] = some_new_slave_name_list
    save_config(config)


def scaledown(diff):
    config = read_config()
    slave_name_list = config.get("slave_names", [])
    # ... modify things...
    slave_name_list = list(set(slave_name_list) - set(slave_list))
    config["slave_names"] = slave_name_list
    save_config(config)
```

(As an aside, since you're doing Docker container management, consider using container labels themselves as the master data for your state management instead of a separate file that can easily go out of sync.)

Comment: oh right, that makes sense. but then how does one update one of the fields of the config file.

Comment: Open for reading, read JSON, update in memory, open for writing, write JSON.

Comment: @dagwood Added an example.

Comment: oh thanks i will have a look at the example. But what if i open in w+ mode and then use the same code that i have written.?

Comment: also what is save_config in the above example that you have given

Comment: write_config was supposed to be save_config, that was a typo. Anyway, using w+ mode will not truncate the file, which means that if the new data is shorter than the old data, you'll be left with something like `"foo": "bar"}ar"}` in the file, which will fail to parse. If you insist on `w+`, you'll have to be careful to truncate the file yourself (`f.truncate()`).

Comment: okay got it thanks but another question: why use save and not dump?

Comment: why use save and not dump ?

Comment: That was another typo. :)

Comment: i have made the all the changes and modeled my code like how u specified https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/LKbStoEFf9 but i am getting this error -> json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Invalid control character at: line 6 column 60 (char 177)

Comment: Your file contains invalid JSON.

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: The JSON decoder can't read line 6, column 60 of your file. There's something wrong there.

Comment: for some reason the new slave lists is not getting updated using ur given method